# Static constructor for the whole assembly

Tags: c#, static, assemblies, initialization

I have many entry points in my assembly and I want some initialization code to be executed once per AppDomain prior to running any other code from this assembly. What would be the best way to do it?

One solution I see is to have a class with static constructor and inherit every entry point I have from it. Something like this:

```
public class Initializer
{
    static Initializer()
    {
        EnsureInitialized();  // Calls initialization code once and only once
    }
}

public class EntryPointOne : Initializer, IEntryPoint
{
    // Some code here
}

public class EntryPointTwo : Initializer, IEntryPoint
{
    // Some code here
}

// etc.
```

This lets me avoid writing boiler plate static constructors in every entry point but without multi-inheritance this is not always possible. Can you think of any other better options?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyload.aspx

Comment: Please clarify whether you want to execute code "once per assembly" or "once per AppDomain". Remember that there can be many assemblies in an AppDomain and depending on the assembly it may be even shared between assemblies (loaded once only).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check [Module initializers in C#](http://tech.einaregilsson.com/2009/12/16/module-initializers-in-csharp/).